# Cert-manager Lets Encrypt certificate not using correct duration in 'spec.durartion' (using default)

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I've setup cert-manager in my k8's environment. Using cert-manager v1.6.1 (latest as of writing)

I've setup a ACME Issuer that uses dns01 challenges.

I've created a certificate resource that specifies the spec.duration as 7 hours.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: mydomain.com
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  secretName: app-certs
  duration: 7h
  renewBefore: 6h
  issuerRef:
    name: acme-issuer
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: mydomain.com
  dnsNames:
    - mydomain.com
```

I can see on the certifiatesigningrequest resource that it interprets the duration that I've set on the certificate.

```
Spec:
  Duration:  7h0m0s
```

Everything seems to come back good on the certificate signing request. No errors or anything and I see the certificate is generated sucessfully.

```
Conditions:
  Last Transition Time:  2021-12-14T20:10:15Z
  Message:               Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
  Reason:                cert-manager.io
  Status:                True
  Type:                  Approved
  Last Transition Time:  2021-12-14T20:10:16Z
  Message:               Certificate fetched from issuer successfully
  Reason:                Issued
  Status:                True
  Type:                  Ready
```

yet the certificate actually is using the default duration (see renewal time)

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-12-14T20:10:16Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Observed Generation:   4
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2022-03-14T19:10:14Z
  Not Before:              2021-12-14T19:10:15Z
  Renewal Time:            2022-03-14T18:30:14Z
```

So is there something I'm doing wrong? I think if the acme challenge failed it wouldn't issue any certificate. How can I set the duration properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Let's Encrypt only allows for 90 day valid certificates ([source](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/09/why-90-days.html)).

> We’re sometimes asked why we only offer certificates with ninety-day lifetimes. People who ask this are usually concerned that ninety days is too short and wish we would offer certificates lasting a year or more, like some other CAs do.

And later on in the article

> Once automated renewal tools are widely deployed and working well, we may consider even shorter lifetimes.

What I ended up doing was specifying the certificate `renewBefore` to when I wanted it to renew.

Other options: You can also look at Step CA certificates which have lower age validity times than Let's Encrypt does.

Comment: Does `renewBefore` work with letsencrypt certificate? Last time I was playing around with it and both `duration` and `renewBefore` were ignored with letsencrypt. By default it happens in `2/3` of duration of certificate. [reference](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/#if-renewbefore-or-duration-is-not-defined-what-will-be-the-default-value)

Comment: My understanding is that`renewBefore` is a cert-manager configuration - it just tells cert-manager when to get a new certificate and that info isn't used when getting a new cert. And `duration` is only a valid parameter for some certificates (like Step-CA).

Comment: Correction - `renewBefore` isn't used when ISSUING a new certificate. It just tells cert-manager when to get a new one.